# What gems should I equip to the Solar-Trans-Lx?

Tags: infinity-blade-3

What gems make the Solar Trans-lx do more damage than 10, and how might I obtain these gems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting any elemental damage gems boosts the damage.

The way this weapon uses the elemental gems is different from most weapons though. Instead of just using the damage listed on the gem, it will add 300 per level of the Solar-Trans weapon, and it starts at level 6 (meaning it will give a bonus of 1800 to whatever gem you equip). Each time you upgrade the weapon, it will boost the gems power by another 300.

[Source](http://infinityblade.wikia.com/wiki/Solar_transport_energy_blades)